# What caused a huge piece of the Sun to break off?

Tags: the-sun, coronal-mass-ejection

There seems to be a huge piece of the sun that broke off at approximately 53 degrees. There's at least [one article](https://metro.co.uk/2023/02/10/part-of-the-sun-broke-off-and-weve-never-seen-anything-like-it-18259267/) that describes it in these terms.

This, to me, seems to be a CME (Coronal Mass Ejection) – it seems that it cannot be a solar flare because it is just a burst of EM radiation. However before this event, there is a high chance that a solar flare happened.

Coincidentally, now the Sun's 11-year solar cycle has completed and during a solar maximum, we see a lot of sunspots.

So my theory is that this is because we have reached the solar maximum, thus magnetic field lines entangle easily, thus this event happened. Is this correct?

Comment: What are you talking about "The Sun's huge piece breaks off approximately 53 degrees"  This doesn't happen.  CME happen all the time.  Has there been one recently? Yes, there is one every day.  Has there been a big one recently? You tell me what you are referring to. The sun is pretty active now.

Comment: We are several years off solar maximum.

Comment: There is a story in the news about this https://metro.co.uk/2023/02/10/part-of-the-sun-broke-off-and-weve-never-seen-anything-like-it-18259267/

Comment: Metro is a pretty much worthless for any kind of science news.

Comment: You'll want to cite the source of any claims that seem sensational.

Comment: As in @JamesK's good answer, there is a misunderstanding from the news report... very nicely clarified in his answer. :)

Comment: I'm guessing it's unlikely the OP will [edit] their question to include the source, but it may well be the article @sno gives a link to – so I'm going to add that link to the question. There are votes to close the post because it's a poor, ill-informed question, but I'd advocate to leave the edited version open, primarily because JamesK's answer is a worthwhile addition to our library for anyone who happens across this article (or any other low-brow "news" article written about this solar event).

Comment: @JamesK  I can support the claim that metro is worthless for science news.

Answer (score 9):

Not a CME, but pretty neat.  This is a prominence, the plasma in the prominence got entrailed into a "vortex" that presumably exists at the solar pole.  The wind speeds in the plasma are pretty extreme.

But this is not "a piece breaking off" (the Sun isn't solid so pieces can't "break off").  The whole "Scientists have never seen it before" statement is rather hyperbolic: the Sun is never the same twice, so there is always something new. However prominences aren't new; n55° refers to the latitude of the prominence.

In particular, our knowledge of the solar poles is limited.  We do now have ESA's solar orbiter which will get a better view, but it is not yet in position.

The current  solar cycle (cycle 25) will peak in about 2025, although the sun is already pretty active.

So a pretty neat observation, but treated in a silly way by the news media (as usual).

Comment: Thanks a lot!, (I totally forgot a solar prominence could also be an option). In the news (Example: https://www.ndtv.com/feature/huge-piece-of-sun-breaks-off-scientists-stunned-3769985), the title isn't technically accurate, because as you pointed out it isn't really a piece breaking off. Is it entailed due to the centripetal acceleration around the sun?